# Why keras always says using theano backend?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, python-import, theano, config.json

I installed keras using conda in my virtual environment and checked $HOME/.keras/config.json file.

```
    {
    "image_data_format": "channels_last",
    "epsilon": 1e-07,
    "floatx": "float32",
    "backend": "tensorflow"
}
```

I already set backend to tensorflow but when I run this in the python console

```
import keras
```

It is showing me that keras is using theano backend. Why?

```
Using Theano backend.
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): install mkl with `conda install mkl-service`: No module named mkl
```

I added `export KERAS_BACKEND=tensorflow` at the end of my .bashrc and restart the command line and activate my source. Still seeing the above error again. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Do you have Tensorflow installed? `import tensorflow` succeeds?

Comment: @nuric: It succeded without an error. `>>> import tensorflow
>>>` What should I do?@nuric

Comment: Are they the same Python version? I don't see a problem directly.

Comment: I fixed it by installing conda then installing all the necessary packages by using pip inside conda. Thankyou @nuric

Answer (score 4):

We had also faced the same issue when installed keras using conda environment. Since we already had keras installed using pip, where the backend was set as theano, it was taking that keras. The problem got fixed when we removed the pip version of keras using the command *pip uninstall keras*

Answer (score 0):

Well you can start your editor with line:

**KERAS_BACKEND=tensorflow**

```
KERAS_BACKEND=tensorflow spyder
```

This would force use the Tensorflow backend.
But before using this ensure that you have tensorflow installed with all the required dependencies.

[Source](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6925#issuecomment-307561628)